# Display Visualforce page on customer portal sidebar?

Tags: apex, visualforce, customer-portal

I have a really simply VF page thats outputs some figures I have in one of my custom objects.
I would like to show this VF page on the side panel (narrow content pane) of my customer portal however VF pages cannot be placed here.

How else can I display this VF page or at least this apex code on the sidebar?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found the answer here:

http://sfdc.arrowpointe.com/2008/09/17/sidebar-summary-using-visualforce/

You need to create a homepage component that contains an iFrame using the page URL:

```
<iframe src="/apex/SidebarSummary" frameborder="0" height="100" width="100%"></iframe>
```